# What is the maximum virtual disk size in KVM

Tags: linux, centos, kvm-virtualization, virtual-disk

We have a server with 12 TB hard disk. I am planning to install KVM. The question is how much maximum disk space one vm can use? I need 5 TB vm disk. is it possible?

Comment: I found on openSUSE page some general and Hardware limitations for KVM. It should be the same also on CentOS, but I am not sure. But it might you give a more insight information about limitations
http://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/html/openSUSE/opensuse-kvm/cha.kvm.limits.html#sec.kvm.limits.hardware

Comment: So have you tried it? If it doesn't work, how about posting the error? I'm rather curious to see how well it turns out.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, depending on the version of `KVM` and `CentOS` you're using and the filesystem under it.  Older versions of `KVM` had a limit of 2TB, and it took a while to "catch up" after the adoption of `GPT` volumes.

`CentOS 5` `ext3`supports up to 16 TB volumes, so as long as you have reasonably recent version of `CentOS`, a modern file system and the version of `KVM` you're running is less than a few years old, you should be fine.